# C program does not recognize my input for 'max'

Tags: c

Hi I keep trying to figuure this out but my input keeps getting ignored, thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    float a, b, a0, b0,i;
    char ans;

    printf("Fibonacci search method\n\nEnter the function:\n");

    printf("\nEnter the intervals over which the Fibonacci method must be applied:\n");

      for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

    printf("a0 = ", i);
    scanf("%f", & a);
    printf("bo = ", i);
    scanf("%f", & b);
  }

    printf("Narrow down on either a maximiser or a minimiser (max/min): \n", ans);
    scanf(" %c", &ans);

    while(ans == 'max'){
        printf("maximum selected");
    }
    printf("minimum selected");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The part `while(ans == 'max') { printf(...) }` will require some time to terminate if the condition evaluates to true. How about using if-then-else instead?.

Comment: How do you expect a single character to equal three characters `max` ??

Comment: the compiler should warn you about this `ans == 'max'`. Always enable compiler warnings and read them

Comment: Welcome to SO. The compiler should warn you about providing more parameters than format specifiers in `printf("a0 = ", i);`.

Comment: Using floating point numbers to control a `for` loop is legal but very uncommon and rarely makes any sense. You probably want to use `int i;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're comparing a single `char` to a whole `string`, so you need to modify your `ans` variable declaration to make it a string, like:

```
char ans[4]
```

Keep in mind, this will have a maximum size of `3`. If you need to store a bigger `string`, you'll need to modify this.
Then, after doing this, using a `while` to do that comparison isn't correct. It's better to implement an `if-else`. And, inside that, the comparison you're doing is wrong. You need to compare `strings`, not `chars`, so you need to use `strcmp()` function, like:

```
strcmp(ans,"max") == 0
```

If this function returns a `0`, it means both strings are equal.
Another thing to comment is that you will need to modify your `scanf` to scan a `string`, not a `char`, the new one will be `scanf("%3s", &ans);`.
And let me tell you one more thing. The `for` you're using has no sense. You're using a `for` with parameters `i = 1; i <= 1; i++`. That means `i` will start the buckle fulfilling the conditions to break it, so it will only be executed once. In other words, the code inside that `for` will be executed just once, no matter if it's inside or outside the `for`.
Anyway, and to sum up, here's your new code:

```
int main(){

    float a, b, a0, b0,i;
    char ans[4];

    printf("Fibonacci search method\n\nEnter the function:\n");

    printf("\nEnter the intervals over which the Fibonacci method must be applied:\n");

    for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        printf("a0 = ", i);
        scanf("%f", & a);
        printf("bo = ", i);
        scanf("%f", & b);
    }

    printf("Narrow down on either a maximiser or a minimiser (max/min): \n", ans);
    scanf("%3s", &ans);

    if(strcmp(ans,"max") == 0)
        printf("maximum selected");
    else
        printf("minimum selected");

    return 0;
}
```